# Make method can be called from class or instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

I want to make a method to be called from class or instance.
For example :

```py
class SomeClass:
    a = 10

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.a = val

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)

SomeClass(20).print_a()    # 20
SomeClass.print_a()    # Error!
```

Here I want to make `print_a` can be called by class either.
If I use `classmethod`, the result is wrong.

```py
class SomeClass:
    a = 10

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.a = val

    @classmethod
    def print_a(cls):
        print(cls.a)
        
SomeClass(20).print_a()    # 10  (wrong!)
SomeClass.print_a()    # 10
```

I hope the result is like this:

```py
SomeClass(20).print_a()    # 20
SomeClass.print_a()    # 10
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`classmethod` is simply a descriptor object, you can read about how it *could* be implemented using pure python in the [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods). Using that implementation as an inspiration:

```
from types import MethodType
class HybridMethod:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        if obj is None:
            return MethodType(self.f, cls)
        else:
            return MethodType(self.f, obj)

class SomeClass:
    a = 10

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.a = val

    @HybridMethod
    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)

SomeClass(20).print_a()    
SomeClass.print_a()
```

Comment: Very thanks! I think I need some time to figure out how this code works.

Comment: @Chun-YeLu read the [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#id1) from the beginning. Also, more details in the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)